# Add Cordova Component to an Existing MAF Application

Tags: cordova, oracle-maf

I need to add a custom login page using the [ADAL-Cordova](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova/) library to an existing Oracle Mobile Application Framework (MAF) application. I'm attempting to do so by creating a MAF feature that loads an index.html page that in turn loads index.js and cordova.js.  When I deploy the app to the device as a pure Cordova app via `cordova run android --device`, the app works and I get prompted for the Azure AD login. However, when I try to manually copy the Cordova artifacts to the MAF app and deploy the MAF app via JDeveloper, it does not work. It loads the page without being preempted by the Azure login, which tells me the Cordova stuff is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the solution is to use the Cordova **plugin**, [cordova-plugin-ms-adal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ms-adal) and integrate that into the MAF app via [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/integrating_a_custom_cordova_plugin)